# What to change after cloning a Linux server?

Tags: linux, virtualization, disk-image

Let's say I'm cloning a virtual machine containing a Linux server.

What would you advice to change in the clone? I know - it's kind of vague and depends on what services ware installed on linux but maybe you can throw some ideas?

Right now I change:

- MAC addresses of virtual interfaces [in fact [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) does it for me]
- re-generate SSH certificates [including host certificates - **rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host*; dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server** in the Debian world]
- change the hostname

What more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- root password change is implied with the "ssh certificates change", I guess
- other certificates: Mail TLS/SSL, Webserver (Apache?) SSL, known-hosts ssh files, other authentification information (Backups? cron-jobs? fetchmail? FTP and ftpd? special repositories (Debian)?
- ip address and routing information (well, depends on the location of the vm, sounds like you just cloned a vm which stays at the same Host-system so it might not be relevant here)
- monitoring: snmpd credentials, maybe automatic data-gathering from other systems?
- add/remove users (and/or their passwords/home-dirs/...)
- Backup procedure
- documentation ;)

You also might want to set on other systems: reverse-dns entries, dns/static routes, update firewall, update central monitoring/syslog...

Comment: better answer than mine though :)

Answer (score 5):

sys-unconfig (in RHEL) will do it all for you

Comment: Never seen that command. I'll have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

1- Change root password for better security ?