# Make a Linux image "unique" after installing it on a new computer

Tags: linux, image

I know about SysPrep for Windows, which should be used after installing a Windows image on a computer to make that computer unique on the network.

Are there any similar steps I should take if I'm using Linux? I have a lot of computers to install it on (identical hardware) and I would like to do it properly. Is there a guide somewhere or could someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 4):

Linux doesn't need the same sysprep/newsid usage as windows machines. Once you've installed the image, since there is no registry, you can simply edit a few files like /etc/hostname to change the machine name, then configure your network settings and you're up.

Redhat has an automated network installation system named [KickStart](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/KickStart-HOWTO.html) which allows you to PXE boot the bare metal machines receiving the install, and then push a pre-configured image to each machine.

Similar systems exist for most of the major linux distributions. They mostly consist of a dhcp and tftp server to PXE boot the machines, a boot image that pulls down the install image/packages, and a config script that sets hostname and other information per machine.

Comment: From my experience I recommend installing cobbler for this purpose. Wirks very good with RedHat based distributions (i.e. RH, Fedora, CentOS, ...). https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/

Answer (score 1):

FAI may be a great solution for you.

Fully Automatic Installation:
http://www.informatik.uni-koeln.de/fai/

Answer (score 1):

some time ago i've asked a bit related questions about [management](https://serverfault.com/questions/32840/automated-linux-deployment-and-config-management-at-small-scale-is-it-worth-it) and [cloning](https://serverfault.com/questions/63367/what-to-change-after-cloning-linux-server). since then i'm using debian pre-seeding combined with puppet and i'm quite happy with it.

if you will end-up cloning - make sure you  at least re-generate ssh private keys for each machine...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the network config sure you remove the udev MAC-address-to-NIC mapping in `/etc/udev/rules.d/*persistent-net*` - otherwise your new machines will come up with eth2/eth3 instead of eth0/eth1 - etc.

But kickstart/fai/systemimager/etc are usually a better solution.